# how to disable special keys in c# window application...?

Tags: c#, window

hii....I am developing  a window application how is it possible to disable special keys like control+alt+del to perform while running the application, i used keyhook method to disable almost all keys like windows,alt+f4 etc....

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It is possible, but I urge you to reconsider its necessity.

Comment: by this user can close the application..but in my application user have not privilege to do such things..so have to restrict such actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, it's pretty low level and would be considered a security risk otherwise. Is there any particular reason you want to disable it?

If you're writing a Kiosk-style application, you will need to write a new GINA DLL that traps the Ctrl-Alt-Del sequence and ignores it. Or just use a keyboard that doesn't *have* a Ctrl, Alt, or Del key...

Comment: i am now doing the application for a home desktop..not for a kiosk system..then while it possible to use gina dll method.. or is thr any simple mehtod...?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+Del is "special" for a reason.

What kind of software are you writing?

Not least, you are forcing me to use a mouse...

Edit

Even if you did write a new GINA DLL, I'd be surprised if you could install it. You won't be able to on a Windows x64 OS without running in test mode etc. Which I would not allow you to do.

So, what kind of software requires you to damage my OS installation?

Comment: yeh its really a special combinaton..but for mi application the client doesnt want such keys to get perform.since a normal keyboard is using,,,,

Comment: i think its practically not good to use it in desktop system, but somehow i have to get a solution for it..thanks for ur information...

Answer (score 0):

To do it there are many ways as writing your own gina.dll (Graphical Identification and Authentication).

But there is an easy way to do so by using registry of the windows.

For this we have to edit the registry at the location :

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

by changing the value of  DisableTaskMgr to 1.

And this is the code  to do it programmatically  in C#

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
public void KillCtrlAltDelete()
        {
            RegistryKey regkey;
            string keyValueInt = "1";
            string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
            try
            {
                regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey);
                regkey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", keyValueInt);
                regkey.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```